# Comparing LPCWSTR in if()

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I feel like I am missing something very obvious here...

In my program, I read user input from an edit box using `GetWindowText()`,
followed by this code:

```
if (x == L"R" || x == L"C" || x == L"L"){ n = 1; }
else{ n = 9; }
```

The debugger clearly says that `x` is `L"R"`, but `n` is getting set as 9.

[image: debugger]

Is using `if()` in this situation wrong and should I use something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c

Comment: How did you declare  the variable `x`, and how did you initialize it? In the bigger picture, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x` is a `wchar*` *pointer*.  The debugger is smart enough to show you the data that `x` is pointing at.  The actual data is elsewhere in memory.

`L"R"` and the other values are *string literals*.  They are implemented as pointers to `wchar_t[]` arrays stored in your app's read-only data segment.

Your `if` statement is comparing pointers to pointers, which will fail if they are not pointing at the same memory (in this case, they do not).  To compare the actual data being pointed at, you need to use `lstrcmpW()` or similar function, eg:

```
if ((lstrcmpW(x, L"R") == 0) ||
    (lstrcmpW(x, L"C") == 0) ||
    (lstrcmpW(x, L"L") == 0))
{
    n = 1;
}
else
{
    n = 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `CString` (becomes `CStringW` in UNICODE build) instead of `LPCWSTR` (in case MFC is used). It does have `operator==()`

```
CString str;
m_DataEdit.GetWindowText(str);

if (str == _T("R") || str == _T("C") || str == _T("L"))
{ 
  n = 1; 
}        
else
{ 
  n = 9; 
}
```

`LPCWSTR` is simply a define for `const WCHAR*`. So you should use `wcscmp`  function for comparison. It is much better if you use `LPCTSTR`, `_tcscmp()` and `_T("")` macro. This combination works well for both **MBCS** and **UNICODE** build.

Comment: Its not clear that's what he wants to do. He may want the first letter from the `EditText`. (That *may* explain the downvote. But I would not have downvoted the answer, personally).

Comment: This only works if the UI is using the MFC framework.  It sounds like the OP is using plain Win32 API calls instead.  The standalone `GetWindowText()` function does not fill a `CString`, it fills a `TCHAR[]` buffer instead.

Comment: It is totally unclear from original post if he does or does not use MFC. So I made an assumption

Comment: `_tcscmp` is for comparing `TCHAR`.  If `WCHAR` is in use, the function is `wcscmp` .

Comment: Correct. Just one addition: TCHAR is defined as WCHAR and _tcscmp becomes wcscmp in case of UNICODE build.

Comment: It is totally clear from the *winapi* tag, that a solution introducing an additional library dependency simply isn't a solution. The sloppiness in execution alone is downvote-worthy, I'm afraid. You certainly meant to use `CStringW` in place of an `LPCWSTR`. Mixing `LPCWSTR` with `_tcscmp` is equally wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Good catch. Made corrections based on your comments.